# Longest Increasing Cyclic Subsequence

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a code for finding the longest increasing subsequence, but I'd like to extend this to allow wrap arounds. For example for the sequence (4,5,6,1,2,3) the longest increasing cyclic subsequence is (1,2,3,4,5,6) since once we reach 3, we can go back to the beginning of the sequence (we can only do this once.) Is anyone able to help me?

Here is the code:

```
def longest_increasing_subsequence(X):

N = len(X)
P = [0] * N
M = [0] * (N+1)
L = 0
for i in range(N):
   lo = 1
   hi = L
   while lo <= hi:
       mid = (lo+hi)//2
       if (X[M[mid]] < X[i]):
           lo = mid+1
       else:
           hi = mid-1

   newL = lo
   P[i] = M[newL-1]
   M[newL] = i

   if (newL > L):
       L = newL

S = []
k = M[L]
for i in range(L-1, -1, -1):
    S.append(X[k])
    k = P[k]
return len(S[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the sequence to the end of itself, then run your algorithm on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the returned value from the function on each shift:

```
max_increasing=longest_increasing_subsequence(X)
for i in range(len(X)-1):
    X=X.append(X.pop(0)) #shift X by 1
    if longest_increasing_subsequence(X)>max_increasing:
         max_increasing=longest_increasing_subsequence(X)
```