# What is the most efficient way of finding the longest increasing subsequence (sorted string) in a circular buffer?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Since the sequence is in a circular buffer, a sequence of 1 2 3 4 would be thought the same as 2 3 4 1, 3 4 1 2, or 4 1 2 3, depending on the starting index.

In this context, what I am trying to find is this:

**Example 1**

In 3 4 1 2 5, the longest increasing subsequence would be 1 2 3 4, not 1 2 5. Of course, this would be easy to find if the sequence started at 1.

**Example 2**

In 1 4 5 2 3, the longest increasing subsequence would be 2 3 4 5, not 1 2 3. This again would be easy to find if the sequence started at 2.

**Example 3**

The sequence 3 4 5 1 2 would be considered sorted, and its LIS would be 1 2 3 4 5.

I am trying to find an algorithm that does this, but all I could find is finding the longest increasing subsequence from a finite sequence, resulting in a shorter subsequence as in the examples. The optimal algorithm of finding LIS from a finite sequence seems to be of O(n log n) as illustrated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms, but the naive way of applying this to my problem would grow to O(n^2 log n), starting over at every number (or letter). Is there a better way of doing this?

I am sorry if I have used the wrong terminologies that might cause confusion.

Comment: Just concatenate two copies of the buffer and search for the LIS there using the usual algorithm (but I guess make sure you do not exceed the length of the original sequence).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I think something like this should work, but it seems hard to prove as the invariants from the original algorithm no longer hold. Do you think you could post an answer if you can work the details out?

Comment: This has technically been asked before: [Longest Increasing Cyclic Subsequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43162136/16757174), but the accepted answer from the several-years-old question is *incorrect*. Simply appending the array to itself and running the normal algorithm *without other checks* fails for: `[14, 12, 6, 5, 15]`, whose longest increasing circular sequence is 2, but would be reported as 3. The other answer on the question is what OP here already found and wanted to improve on. I couldn't find any other examples of this question being answered on SO.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for the suggestion. However, I had tried concatenating a sequence with itself but one element shorter, for example, 1 2 4 3 with 1 2 4, resulting in 1 2 4 3 1 2 4. Applying the algorithm on the wiki article, the LIS turns out to be 1 2 3 4, which is problematic since it skips the first 4 and takes the second 4.

Comment: @kcsquared Thank you for the link. I did not know it was asked before. But it seems like there isn't a satisfying answer to the question.

Comment: The 'Longest increasing circular subsequence problem' appears to be harder than the LIS version. There's an `O(n^(1.5) log n)` [Monte Carlo algorithm here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019006002523) with better average performance, and some algorithms whose runtime depends on the output length of the Longest Increasing Circular Subsequence (LICS) (so might be faster), but there doesn't seem to be any published `O(n log n)` algorithm.

Comment: @kcsquared Thank you so much for the follow-up. I have just read the article and it was exactly addressing the problem. I will look into the Monte Carlo algorithm. Thanks!